# My hovers doesn't work anymore.. i dont know why :(

Tags: hover, navbar, effect

I honestly trying this to fix now for literally about 12 hours.. I can't get my hovers to work.
I switched my website to another host, and they simply doesnt work anymore.. idk why

Host before: [www.youbetterrun.de](http://www.youbetterrun.de) (**as you see they still work there, try to hover over the navbar and on the Vote Images on the left**)

Host after: [www.l2xenoth.com](http://www.l2xenoth.com) - **i had my site before on this host in /site2 (in this directory they worked.. idk why) then i switched them to the default directoy and they dont work now..**

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

you have some path problem with JQuery, see the errors in the image below, so check the dependencies and their path !

[image]

**UPDATE**

you can see in the bottom left of the screenshot, in js folder there is no jquery

[image]

Comment: The scripts are in /js/ folder. Also, in my Index.php the paths seems to be right. <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dotdotdot.js"></script>

Comment: @DeWayneCacian JQuery is missing, i updated the answer, see the new image

Comment: I don't think so. The file is existing i think. http://prntscr.com/kekggi